# Trigger Scrollviewer with canvas.children elements

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

*I am trying to trigger scrollviewer but it doesnt work since i think it depends on the objects parents of content-template. Excuse me for bad english. There is a statement before within a loop that checks if it fullfills some statement if it fullfills this modiefier appears.

**Backend:**

```
Vector post = new Vector(60, 40);
                        positionTM = positionTM + post;
                        tblLvl1 = new TableObjects(
                            Application.Current.Resources["ShapeTS"] as ControlTemplate,
                              DependencyList[i].ObjectName,
                               "/assets/item.png",
                               positionTM,
                               rep.OnDragDelta,
                                DependencyList[j].ID,
                              DependencyList[j].RelatedObjectID, DependencyList[j].StartTime, DependencyList[j].RowsInserted, DependencyList[j].ExecutionTime);
                        tblLvl1.DataContext = tblLvl1;
                        rep.mycanvas.Children.Add(tblLvl1);
                        rep.connection.Children.Add(tblLvl1.LinkTo(tblLvl0));
```

**Frontend :**

```
 <ScrollViewer
        x:Name="scroller"
        CanContentScroll="True"
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
        >
            <Grid x:Name="sqlrelation">
                <Grid.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"/>
                        <SkewTransform AngleX="0" AngleY="0"/>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="0"/>
                        <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Grid.RenderTransform>
                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="30" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="#FF837F7F" >
                    <Button Click="Enlarge_Click" ToolTip="Enlarge">
                        <Image Source="assets/enlarge.png"></Image>
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
                <Canvas Name="mycanvas"  MouseWheel="Mycanvas_MouseWheel"
                      >
                    <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                        <MatrixTransform/>
                    </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                    <Canvas>
                        <Path Stroke="#FF2062A3" StrokeThickness="3">
                            <Path.Data>
                                <GeometryGroup x:Name="connection"></GeometryGroup>
                            </Path.Data>
                        </Path>
                    </Canvas>
                </Canvas>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
```